# Magento PHP Pricing Divide Price by Pack QTY

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am trying to divide product price by pack to display an each price.

My PHP knowledge is very poor, so any help/direction would be a massive help.

Each product/price is part of a pack, I will be selling by the pack price but I would also like to display an each price.

So far I have the following:

```
<?php $_packAmount = $_product->getPack(); ?>
                <?php $_productPrice = $_product->getPrice(); ?>
                <?php $_each = $_productPrice / $_packAmount; ?>
                <?php echo (round($_each,2)); ?>
```

This appears to work ok, but if the product is using a special price it ignores the special price and uses the main product price.

I need to be able to divide by the product price it is using at the time (regular or special price) also needs to display in the correct currency.

I have also setup an additional attribute in back end called "mkt_price" I would like this to override the each price if a value exists.

Thanks in advance (Magento version 1.9.2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use:

```
product->getFinalPrice()
```

This should get the final price.

```
foreach ($collection as $product){
    if($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){
       // Your code here

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Steven, this does not seem to work, are you able to paste full code including my own so I can try? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Sorry can I confirm which template .phtml file you are currently editing?